# check look up values of dynamics 365 entities inside power automate

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I want to know how can I compare a field of an entity with a dropdown list or a lookup value in dynamics 365 power automate?

for example, I want to send an email to a case customer when a case is created if the case type is "complain,request" , but I don't want to write those words, it doesn't pick up values like the workflows??

Thanks

Comment: did the mentioned answer helped?

Answer (score 0):

Flow/PowerAutomate does have condition to check for type.
I just tried on case Entity. For every Type you will have a value behind it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I understand this for types, what about lookups?

Comment: you can work with lookup as well. if it helped Could you please mark this as solved

Comment: how can i do it with lookups? I cannot see that